# Metro app - sqlite c# update database using List<>

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, microsoft-metro

i have problem with update my sqlite database in Metro App (c#).
How can i update all information from List<> to database?

I using this code:

```
var update = dbdata.First();    
await db.UpdateAsync(update);
```

or

```
var update = dbdata.Last();    
await db.UpdateAsync(update);
```

This code update database using only first/last line from my List dbdata, how can i update db using all line from my list?

Comment: OK, i do it like this:

    int x=0;
    foreach (var e in dbdata)
     {
      var update = dbdata.ElementAt(x);
      await db.UpdateAsync(update);
      x++;
     }

but i think this is not the best idea (bad performance in biggest db?) :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, i do it like this:

```
int x=0;
foreach (var e in dbdata)
 {
  var update = dbdata.ElementAt(x);
  await db.UpdateAsync(update);
  x++;
 }
```

but i think this is not the best idea (bad performance in biggest db?) :)